# SQL Server CASE .. WHEN .. IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, case-when

On SQL server 2005 I am trying to query this select statement

```
SELECT AlarmEventTransactionTableTable.TxnID,
       CASE AlarmEventTransactions.DeviceID
         WHEN DeviceID IN( '7', '10', '62', '58',
                           '60', '46', '48', '50',
                           '137', '139', '142', '143', '164' )
           THEN '01'
         WHEN DeviceID IN( '8', '9', '63', '59',
                           '61', '47', '49', '51',
                           '138', '140', '141', '144', '165' )
           THEN '02'
         ELSE 'NA'
       END AS clocking,
       AlarmEventTransactionTable.DateTimeOfTxn
FROM   multiMAXTxn.dbo.AlarmEventTransactionTable
```

It returns the error below

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4   Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'IN'.

Please give me some advice on what could be wrong with my code.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`CASE AlarmEventTransactions.DeviceID` should just be `CASE`.

You are mixing [the 2 forms of the `CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I ahve fixed it to look like below

Answer (score 14):

Try this...

```
SELECT
    AlarmEventTransactionTableTable.TxnID,
    CASE
        WHEN DeviceID IN('7', '10', '62', '58', '60',
                 '46', '48', '50', '137', '139',
                 '142', '143', '164') THEN '01'
        WHEN DeviceID IN('8', '9', '63', '59', '61',
                 '47', '49', '51', '138', '140',
                 '141', '144', '165') THEN '02'
        ELSE 'NA' END AS clocking,
    AlarmEventTransactionTable.DateTimeOfTxn
 FROM
    multiMAXTxn.dbo.AlarmEventTransactionTable
```

Just remove highlighted string

SELECT
    AlarmEventTransactionTableTable.TxnID,
    CASE **AlarmEventTransactions.DeviceID**
        WHEN DeviceID IN('7', '10', '62', '58', '60', ...)

Comment: I have fixit as CASE WHEN DeviceID IN('7', '10', '62', '58', '60', '46', '48', '50', '137', '139', '141', '145', '164') THEN '01'
WHEN DeviceID IN('8', '9', '63', '59', '61','47', '49', '51', '138', '140','142', '146', '165') THEN '02' ELSE 'NA' END AS clocking,

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the Answer 
I have modified the statements to look like below

```
SELECT
     AlarmEventTransactionTable.TxnID,
     CASE 
    WHEN DeviceID IN('7', '10', '62', '58', '60',
            '46', '48', '50', '137', '139',
             '141', '145', '164') THEN '01'
    WHEN DeviceID IN('8', '9', '63', '59', '61',
            '47', '49', '51', '138', '140',
            '142', '146', '165') THEN '02'
             ELSE 'NA' END AS clocking,
     AlarmEventTransactionTable.DateTimeOfTxn
FROM
     multiMAXTxn.dbo.AlarmEventTransactionTable
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to read when written out in longhand using the 'simple case' e.g.

```
CASE DeviceID 
   WHEN '7  ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '10 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '62 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '58 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '60 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '46 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '48 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '50 ' THEN '01'
   WHEN '137' THEN '01'
   WHEN '139' THEN '01'
   WHEN '142' THEN '01'
   WHEN '143' THEN '01'
   WHEN '164' THEN '01'
   WHEN '8  ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '9  ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '63 ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '59 ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '61 ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '47 ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '49 ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '51 ' THEN '02'
   WHEN '138' THEN '02'
   WHEN '140' THEN '02'
   WHEN '141' THEN '02'
   WHEN '144' THEN '02'
   WHEN '165' THEN '02'
   ELSE 'NA' 
END AS clocking
```

...which kind makes me thing that perhaps you could benefit from a lookup table to which you can `JOIN` to eliminate the `CASE` expression entirely.

Answer (score 0):

the case sintax it easy:

CASE

WHEN condition THEN result

WHEN condition THEN result

ELSE result END’

please check thi article about sql case https://thedevelopmentstages.com/select-case-sql-como-usar-ejemplos/