# CASE Statement SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, case

Using pubs db I have created the following with UNION ALL, but was trying to do the same with a CASE stmt.

```
SELECT 
t.title_id AS 'Title ID',
t.ytd_sales 'YTD Sales',
t.price AS 'Original Price',
          'New Price' = CASE t.ytd_sales
           WHEN (t.ytd_sales < 2500.00) THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND   (t.price*1.15,2))
           WHEN (t.ytd_sales BETWEEN 2500.00 AND 10000.00) THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND(t.price*1.10,2))
           WHEN (t.ytd_sales > 10000.00) THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND(t.price*1.05,2))
           ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND(t.price*1.00,2))
        END

    FROM titles t  
    ;
```

It does not like to comparison/special operators. is this even possible to do as a CASE stmt?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server CASE .. WHEN .. IN statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042767/sql-server-case-when-in-statement)

Comment: You are mixing the 2 forms of the CASE statement.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, as Martin Smith indicates, this question is a duplicate of  [SQL Server CASE .. WHEN .. expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042767/sql-server-case-when-in-statement).

The proper syntax for this query would be

```
SELECT 
t.title_id  AS [Title ID],
t.ytd_sales AS [YTD Sales],
t.price     AS [Original Price],
CASE  
       WHEN (t.ytd_sales < 2500.00) THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND   (t.price*1.15,2))
       WHEN (t.ytd_sales BETWEEN 2500.00 AND 10000.00) THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND(t.price*1.10,2))
       WHEN (t.ytd_sales > 10000.00) THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND(t.price*1.05,2))
       ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),ROUND(t.price*1.00,2))
    END     AS [New Price]

FROM dbo.titles t  
;
```

At the risk of being preachy: column aliases should be in square brackets (`as [Title ID]`), not single quotes (that are for string literals).  Ref: [TSQL SELECT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx)

Comment: Thank you SO much, Stan - appreciate any and all the direction I can get as I am new to this stuff. Appreciate your patience!

Comment: Follow up - of course your tweak worked like a charm.  Thanks again...I now see all the mistakes I made!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to mix up two styles of `CASE` statements in SQL.

The syntax for the CASE statement in SQL Server (Transact-SQL) is:

**Scenario 1:** When you have a simple logic where expression will be compared to each values provided:

```
CASE expression

   WHEN value_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN value_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN value_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

**OR**

**Scenario 1:** When you have more complex logic where you have different conditions to evaluate:

```
CASE

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

Courtesy:[SQL Server: Case Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php)