# Case When in SQL , Two Different Attributes

Tags: sql

New to the forum. I am looking to use a CASE WHEN function based on two separate fields . Those fields are `order day` and `Month` . `Month` is a calculation from:

```sql
DATEPART (Month, order_day ) AS Month
```

The code I have is below, but not getting the desired result. Want to say when `order day` is between x dates, then have the data in the `Month` column 1, otherwise give me the normal data that appears in the `Month` column.

```sql
when order_day between to_date ('20201227', 'YYYYMMDD') and TO_DATE  ('20201231', 'YYYYMMDD') THEN Month = '1'
else Month End As Month2
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042767/sql-server-case-when-in-statement

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Why the hard-coded context of the from/to dates? and your "else Month end" part of the case/when is confusing.  Do you mean to grab the month representation from the "Order_Day" column?  What happens if you change your query in a few months and looking for activity between the month March 8 - March 27?  Does that become 1 and everything else become 3 (March is 3rd month of year?) ?  Please edit your original question and revise clarification and context why case/when.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to understand the question, but your `case when` in a `SELECT` statement should look like this:

```
SELECT 
  case when order_day between to_date ('20201227', 'YYYYMMDD') and TO_DATE('20201231', 'YYYYMMDD')
    then Month = '1' 
    else Month 
  end
```

Comment: The error was caused by repeating the "month" column name after the THEN part of the argument..

Comment: Once I learn how to resolve this thread I will

Comment: Even your query case/when does no make sense.  Your use case/when I suspect would fail as "Month" is a probably a function name, not a column.  They were resulting in a final column name of "Month2".  Their question is not exactly clear.